# Why is my application stops working after 300 records?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that returns a list of data, `List <t>` through a web method that worked fine from the beginning, until the number of returned records passed 300, try using try catch to see where in the code it will be generates the error and only when the method finishes executing it generates the following exception.

`'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Extensions.dll`

This is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string cargarRegNacViv(string dato, string opc, string fechaMin, string fechaMax)
{
    List<CRRegNacViv> RegNacVivs = new List<CRRegNacViv>();
    if (opc == "Código RUAF")
    {
        CRCodRuaf CodRuaf = DAOCRCodRuaf.getCodRuaf(dato);
        RegNacVivs = DAOCRRegNacViv.getRegNacViv(Convert.ToString(CodRuaf.IntOIdCRCodRuaf), opc);
    }
    else
        RegNacVivs = DAOCRRegNacViv.getRegNacVivs(dato, opc);

    List<double> codRuaf = new List<double>();
    foreach (CRRegNacViv NacViv in RegNacVivs)
    {
        codRuaf.Add(DAOCRCodRuaf.getCodRuafId(Convert.ToString(NacViv.IntCRCodRuaf)).DoubleCRcodRuaf);
    }

    Object[] datos = { RegNacVivs, codRuaf };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
}
```

la consola muestra el siguiente mensaje cuando el metodo termina
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xma5c.jpg)

other methods

```
public static List<CRRegNacViv> getRegNacViv(string dato, string opc)
        {
            List<CRRegNacViv> RegNacVivs = new List<CRRegNacViv>();
            //RegNacVivs = null;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader reader;
            Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
            string tabla = "";

            switch (opc)
            {
                case "Documento Madre": tabla = "IdMadre"; break;
                case "Nombre Madre": tabla = "NomMadre"; break;
                case "Tipo Parto": tabla = "TipNac"; break;
                case "Código RUAF": tabla = "OidCRCodRuaf"; break;
                case "Documento Médico": tabla = "GNCodUsu"; break;
            }

            try
            {
                command = new SqlCommand("select * from CRNacidoVivo WHERE " + tabla + "= '" + dato + "'  ", conexion.OpenConnection());
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabla", tabla);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CRRegNacViv regNacViv = new CRRegNacViv();
                    regNacViv.DoubleIdMadre = Convert.ToDouble(reader["IdMadre"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.StrNomMadre = reader["NomMadre"].ToString();
                    regNacViv.StrTipNac = reader["TipNac"].ToString();
                    regNacViv.DateFecNac = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FecNac"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.IntCRCodRuaf = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OIdCRCodRuaf"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.IntEdGesNac = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EdadGes"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.DoubleGNCodUsu = Convert.ToDouble(reader["GNCodUsu"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.StrNomDoc = reader["NomDoc"].ToString();
                    regNacViv.IntPesoRn = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PesoRN"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.FloatTallaRN = float.Parse(reader["TallaRN"].ToString());
                    regNacViv.StrSexo = reader["Sexo"].ToString();
                    RegNacVivs.Add(regNacViv);
                }
                 
                

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               
            }
            finally
            {
                conexion.CloseConnection();
            }
            return RegNacVivs;
        }


public static CRCodRuaf getCodRuafId(string OIdCRCodRuaf)
        {
            CRCodRuaf codRuaf = new CRCodRuaf();
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader reader;
            Conexion conexion = new Conexion();

            try
            {
                command = new SqlCommand("select * from CRCodRuaf where OIdCRCodRuaf = @CRcodRuaf ", conexion.OpenConnection());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CRcodRuaf", OIdCRCodRuaf);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    codRuaf = new CRCodRuaf
                    {
                        IntOIdCRCodRuaf = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OIdCRCodRuaf"]),
                        DateFecCod = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FecCod"]),
                        StrIncidencia = reader["Incidencia"].ToString(),
                        IsEstado = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Estado"]),
                        StrTipCodigo = reader["TipCodigo"].ToString(),
                        DoubleGNCodUsu = Convert.ToDouble(reader["GNCodUsu"]),
                        DoubleCRcodRuaf = Convert.ToDouble(reader["CRcodRuaf"]),

                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception wi)
            {

                
            }
            finally
            {
                conexion.CloseConnection();
            }



            return codRuaf;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe record 301 has some data that cannot be converted to string. There should be more detail to that exception.

Comment: Or perhaps it exceeds some IIS length or JSON serialisation limit.

Comment: I tested the serialization to JSON and it worked fine, I think the problem is in the length of the string passes what is allowed by a WebMethod

Comment: How can you know in your 301 record the function `getCodRuafId` does return an object? You are not checking if it returned anything before accesing its `DoubleCRcodRuaf` property. That code could potentially raise and `NullReferenceException`

Comment: If you're having difficulty finding where the error is occurring, you can put try-catch blocks around each of your statements. Ensure you put some unique text when outputing the error message.  (ex: "Error (1)..."). Also if you have a statement that is doing multiple things, such as `codRuaf.Add(DAOCRCodRuaf.getCodRuafId(Convert.ToString(NacViv.IntCRCodRuaf)).DoubleCRcodRuaf);`, for debugging, break it up into multiple statements.

Comment: user9938  gracias por tu ayuda, pero  el metodo funciona bien en todo momento sin ecepciones, solo cuando termina de ejecutarse me muestra el la excepcion por consola

Comment: What is the namespace for Conexion in Conexion conexion = new Conexion();   It doesn't look like any parameters were passed or properties set (ie: ConnectionString). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Solved! the error was in the webservice configuration that did not allow the number of characters to be sent.

in the web.config i put this

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```